# How to redefine operations for Scala type tags

Tags: scala, types, operator-overloading, shapeless

Suppose I have a tagged type eg.:

```
import shapeless.tag.@@
import shapeless.tag

trait VolumeTag
type Volume = Double @@ VolumeTag

def Volume(value: Double): Volume = tag[Volume][Double](value)
```

Now, the problem I have is, that, for example when I add two objects of type `Volume`, I get a double. How can I redefine the `+` operator, so that the return value for two volumes is a volume?

I have tried adding a new trait eg. `VolumeOperations` that redefines `+` for objects of type `Volume`. But I wasn't able to implement `+` without using `.isInstanceOf[Volume]`.

Is it possible to achieve this without casting?

Answer (score 2):

You can define extension method

```
def Volume(value: Double): Volume = tag[VolumeTag][Double](value)

implicit class VolumeOp(v: Volume) {
  //def +(v1: Volume): Volume = Volume(v + v1)
  def plus(v1: Volume): Volume = Volume(v + v1)
}
```

But `tag` is actually casting.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I can define an additional `plus(v1: Volume)` function in `VolumeOp` and it will work. However, redefining `+` will not (ie. adding two volumes will still return a double, somehow the new + is not found, but the one in double). I'm using Scala 2.13.1

Comment: @BKE Yea, you're right. Extension will work with `plus`, not with `+`. You can make `def Volume` implicit and then write `Volume(1.0) + Volume(2.0) : Volume`.

Comment: I'm not sure why doesn't it work, and it kind of defeats the purpose. It's hardly nicer than just writing Volume(Volume(1.0) + Volume(2.0). But if you can explain why it can not work the way I wanted, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @BKE Compiler doesn't select method defined with implicits if there is already explicit method with the same name. https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#views

Comment: Ok, and would there be a solution without implicits?